# Graph Goat Teleportation Data with Google Vis. API via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-visualization

I just checked my Chromium task manager and noticed that my `Goats Teleported` count is abnormally high. I thought it might be a good idea to create a browser extension that runs the goat teleportation data through Google Visualizations API and generates some nice reports so I can track it easily and make sure it doesn't get out of hand.

[image]

Is it possible to access the `Goats Teleported` count programatically via the chrome extension API? How do you think I should format the reports? I was thinking maybe a pie chart?

[image]

Comment: You can also see the impact that this is having at https://www.google.com/trends/correlate/search?e=goat&t=weekly&p=us#

Comment: @naught101: manual transmission? digitizer? free hotspot? That's really odd.

Comment: [Never use a pie chart.](https://blogs.oracle.com/experience/entry/countdown_of_top_10_reasons_to_never_ever_use_a_pie_chart) even if your example it gets very hard to meaningfully compare the sizes of anything past the top two.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is an [experimental `processes` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/dev/experimental.processes.html) where one would expect to find such important info exposed. But alas, `Goats Teleported` isn’t yet available through that API. I think you’ve uncovered a major hole in the extension system and urge you to [file a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry).

+1 for goats.