# A long bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, long-integer

How can I get a long number bigger than Long.MAX_VALUE?

I want this method to return `true`:

```
boolean isBiggerThanMaxLong(long val) {
    return (val > Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

That method can't return `true`.  That's the *point* of `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  It would be *really* confusing if its name were...  false.  Then it should be just called `Long.SOME_FAIRLY_LARGE_VALUE` and have literally zero reasonable uses.  Just use [Android's `isUserAGoat`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13375357/1339987), or you may roll your own function that always returns `false`.

Note that a `long` in memory takes a fixed number of bytes.  [From Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> long: The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive). Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int.

As you may know from basic computer science or discrete math, there are 2^64 possible values for a long, since it is 64 bits.  And as you know from discrete math or number theory or common sense, if there's only finitely many possibilities, one of them has to be the largest.  That would be `Long.MAX_VALUE`.  So you are asking something similar to "is there an integer that's >0 and < 1?"  Mathematically nonsensical.

If you actually need this for something for real then use `BigInteger` class.

Comment: Someone should work on breaking isUserAGoat API ether by inventing teleportation or at least create an android gadget for goats.

Comment: @gongshw assuming `triangle.lborderA` is a `long` then you can delete that check.  I wouldn't be surprised if it optimizes out.

Comment: The source code to test contains the judgment "triangle.lborderA > 0 && triangle.lborderA <= Long.MAX_VALUE". So it seems that i cannot make my unit test 100% coverage.

Comment: @gongshw try `lborderA < 0` to fail that check.  Similarly you cannot fail a check that says `if(Boolean.TRUE)`.

Comment: @Mr.Me Well, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13375461/507738), if you download the package `com.coffeestainstudios.goatsimulator`, then the teleportation of goats can commence!

Comment: here you get a good explaination of the data types https://xenovation.com/blog/development/java/what-is-a-data-type-in-java

Answer (score 14):

You can't. If you have a method called `isBiggerThanMaxLong(long)` it should always return `false`.

If you were to increment the bits of `Long.MAX_VALUE`, the next value should be `Long.MIN_VALUE`. Read up on twos-complement and that should tell you why.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the below method doesn't compile as it is missing the return type and it should be `Long.MAX_VALUE` in place of `Long.Max_value`.

```
public static boolean isBiggerThanMaxLong(long value) {
      return value > Long.Max_value;
}
```

The above method can never return  `true` as you are comparing a `long` value with `Long.MAX_VALUE` , see the method signature you can pass only `long` there.Any `long` can be as big as the `Long.MAX_VALUE`, it can't be bigger than that.

You can try something like this with [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class :

```
public static boolean isBiggerThanMaxLong(BigInteger l){
    return l.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE))==1?true:false;
}
```

The below code will return `true` :

```
BigInteger big3 = BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).
                  add(BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));
System.out.println(isBiggerThanMaxLong(big3)); // prints true
```

Answer (score 4):

If `triangle.lborderA` is indeed a long then the test in the original code is trivially true, and there is no way to test it. It is also useless.

However, if `triangle.lborderA` is a double, the comparison is useful and can be tested. `isBiggerThanMaxLong(1e300)` does return true.

```
  public static boolean isBiggerThanMaxLong(double in){
    return in > Long.MAX_VALUE;
  }
```

Comment: isBiggerThanMaxLong(Long.MAX_VALUE + 1.0) will return false. isBiggerThanMaxLong(Long.MAX_VALUE + 1024.0) will also return false. You get true with doubles >= Long.MAX_VALUE + 1025.0

Comment: @Samil True. It would return true for any double that is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE, of which there are many. Because of floating point rounding, Long.MAX_VALUE+1.0 is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember BigInteger is a class and long is a primitive. If you want to compare large values than long_max_value, wrap your value in the BigInteger class and treat them as objects.

Answer (score 0):

A "long" greater than the maximum value of long just doesn't exist , rather i suggest you use the biginteger  class , and caste the maximum value of long to a biginteger.