# How to return the original log retention after purge kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, purge

We have 3 kafka machines version - **0.10.0.2.6**

We want to purge all data files from all kafka's topics ( purge completely all data )

The CLI for this action should be ( should be run from the zoo server )

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic1 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic2 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic3 --config retention.ms=1000
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic Topic4 --config retention.ms=1000
.
```

.
.

Since we Temporarily update the retention time on the topic to one second (1000 ms )

Then how to return the previous original retention!

Note - **log.retention.hours = 168** ( from the ambari GUI ) and this is the original value

So how to return the original value (**168** hours) back on all topics ? after purge all Topics?

**LIST OF TOPICS**

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh  --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
__consumer_offsets 
_schemas
hrtfsa.polr.mdr.initial
hrtfsa.polr.pri.content_analysis
hrtfsa.polr.pri.decoded
hrtfsa.polr.pri.enriched.suspected_relation
hrtfsa.polr.pri.id_correlation
hrtfsa.polr.pri.processed
hrtfsa.polr.suspected_relations
hrtfsa.monitoring.heartbeat
```

I found this ( https://gist.github.com/dmitz/47e230b35d84df900c2d57370f4e85b2 )

purge the topic:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper <zookeeper_address> --alter --topic <topic_name> --config retention.ms=1000
```

return the orig value of retention:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper <zookeeper_address> --alter --topic <topic_name> --delete-config retention.ms
```

Is this correct for version 0.10.0.2.6 ?

Comment: 1) Calculate 168 hrs to millisecond 2) Create file with list of topics 3) Loop over content, executing command https://stackoverflow.com/q/1521462/2308683

Comment: so to return the 168 hours need to set the CLI like this:

Comment: kafka-topics --zookeeper <zookeeper_address> --alter --topic <topic_name> --config retention.ms=604800000

Comment: Looks correct to me. I don't think there's a way to "reset configuration" to the defaults

Comment: my question is - 604800000 is long number , I worry if CLI have limit to accept this number ?

Comment: It's parsed by Java, not the CLI. And it's fine https://stackoverflow.com/a/16546077/2308683

Comment: another question please - so you not accept what was wrote in the following link ?https://gist.github.com/dmitz/47e230b35d84df900c2d57370f4e85b2 )

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of `--delete-config` option.