# spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate or update returns beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

so far I only have a simple empty Spring application (only `main()`) with the database configurations (Oracle) and the dependencies as you can see below.

During the first test run it turned out that if I use `validate` or `update` instead `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` the following errors occurs (see Error Messages). With `create-drop` the application would start and work with only one error: "ERROR o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow"

I would be very happy if you would help me. Previous forum entries were unfortunately not successful.

**application propperties**

*Oracle settings*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//example:1521/example
spring.datasource.username=User
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.continueOnError: true
spring.batch.initialize-schema=always
```

*HikariCP settings*

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
```

*Logging*

```
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

*JPA/Hibernate*

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>OracleDatabaseConnection</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OracleDatabaseConnection</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Entity Class

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="AMP_MS_USER") 
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="USER_SEQUENCE")
      @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MS_USER_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1, name = "USER_SEQUENCE")
    @Column(name="id_calcuser")
    private Long id_calcuser;
    

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public User() {
        
    }

    public User(String username, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId_calcuser() {
        return id_calcuser;
    }

    public void setId_calcuser(Long id_calcuser) {
        this.id_calcuser = id_calcuser;
    }

    

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**Sequence in SQL Developer**

```
-- Create sequence 
create sequence MS_USER_SEQUENCE
minvalue 1
maxvalue 9999999999999999999999999999
start with 1
increment by 1
cache 20;
```

**Error Messages**

```
2020-04-20 13:53:11 ERROR o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4136)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getLong(NumberCommonAccessor.java:591)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:259)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:558)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetMinValue(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570032/hibernate-could-not-fetch-the-sequenceinformation-from-the-database)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your answer. For me it's more helpful to solve the bugs ('entityManagerFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException...) with "validate" or "update" configuations. With "create-drop" I just wanted to show that here the application works, even if with the error of Sequence Information.

Comment: The "bug" is Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow So it's the same for all options

Comment: sounds like an issue with your ID generation. Can you post the code for your JPA Entity?

Comment: I have added the entity class and id generation sequence above :)

Answer (score 1):

You problem is with MIN_VALUE - this is visible in the exception `SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetMinValue`

It menas there is defined a *descending sequence* with a high (default) MIN_VALUE that must be reset.

Note that this is not necessary the sequence you use, it is a sequence your user can access. See more details in the corrresponding [Hibernate BUG](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13694)

**1) find which sequence it is**

```
select SEQUENCE_OWNER, SEQUENCE_NAME, MIN_VALUE from ALL_SEQUENCES order by min_value;
```

You will see most probably on the top a sequence with MIN_VALUE   `-999999999999999999999999999`

Now you have two possibilities how to workaround - either 2) or 3)

**2) resize the MIN_VALUE**

supply propper owner and sequence name and set the value to min allowed [long value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546038/a-long-bigger-than-long-max-value)

```
ALTER SEQUENCE ooo.seq_xxxxx 
  MINVALUE   -9223372036854775808;
```

**3) revoke the access to the sequence**

If the sequence is not used by Hibernate simple revoke it from your connecting USER, it will disappear from ALL_SEQUENCES and make no harm any more.

Supply the propper sequence and connection user names

```
 revoke  select on  ooo.seq_xxxxx from connection_user;
```

You may need to call your DBA to do this.

Comment: Thank Marmite, but there doesn't exist a mentioned minimum value. I selected my sequences asc and smallest minimum value is 0 and biggest 10000000000000000000
 :(

Comment: You found the problem - `10000000000000000000` fails obviously to be converted to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to change the max of your sequence or change the data type for your ID.

```
Your sequence:     9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999
Max positive long: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Comment: This  basically repeats (partly) the anwser of the duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574009/4808122) and is most probably *not relevant* in this case where the exception is caused by `resultSetMinValue` - check the exception in Q.

Comment: Tanks Ramir :), I changed to maxvalue 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. However, the bug remains.

Comment: The exception is coming from the Oracle JDBC driver. Are you using the correct version for your database?

Comment: Changing the **max** value will not help (at this stage) when the problem is in the **min** value. @JJB91 see the alternative answer.